# fancybox onClosed callback does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox

I am using fancyBox v2.0.4 ...

Well this should be simple, however it does not work in my case... I simply want to run a callback function when the fancybox is closed...

```
$('a#stpa_announcement_details_open').fancybox({
    'onCleanup': function() { alert('test') },
    'hideOnContentClick': true
});
```

does not work

```
$('a#stpa_announcement_details_open').fancybox({
    'onClosed': function() { alert('test') },
    'hideOnContentClick': true
});
```

does not work

Answer (score 17):

You are using options from older versions, so it would be like -

```
$('a#stpa_announcement_details_open').fancybox({
    'beforeClose': function() { alert('test') },
    'closeClick': true
});
```

You can find these options at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('a#stpa_announcement_details_open').fancybox({
   'afterClose': function() {
                               alert('test') 
                             }
  });
```

Hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

use beforeClose or afterClose. Find the API documentation under the Callbacks tab here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs