# Call a function when fancybox is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I would like to call `parent.window.clearInterval(wpupdate)` when the user closes the 'fancybox', either by clicking a link inside the frame, or when clicking the area around it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure FancyBox probably has some sort of "onClose" method you can have invoked  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250540/fancybox-onclosed-callback-does-not-work

Comment: afterClose  Called after closing animation has ended

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can find in the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/%5D#docs) ( *Callbacks* tab ) there are 2 methods for you:

1. beforeClose
   Called right after closing has been triggered but not yet started
   Note: If false is returned by the callback, the closing will be halted.
2. afterClose
   Called after closing animation has ended

Answer (score 0):

From the site you pointed to you have the following options as CallBacks:

beforeClose  Called right after closing has been triggered but not yet started 
Note: If false is returned by the callback, the closing will be halted.

afterClose   Called after closing animation has ended